# How to replace the following special character is a string ï¿½ in C#

Tags: c#, string, character

In c#, how can I replace the character below which are part of a string with a blank space?

ï¿½

I tried using the code below but not happens.

line = line.Replace("ï¿½", "");

Comment: This is working on my side, would you mind showing a part of the code/string you are using?

Comment: Wherever you're getting that string from is probably a different encoding than whatever is showing you “ï¿½”. That means the string isn't actually “ï¿½”.

Comment: You could explain where this string comes from. There's probably a good way to avoid this *problem* treating the source the right way (wrong encoding, probably, as already noted)

Comment: The ASCII value of the character is 160

Comment: And the original Unicode (UTF-8 or UTF-16LE) value?

Comment: No, the ASCII value of the character is not 160, because ASCII only goes up to 127 base-10. You have to find out what encoding the data is in before you go further.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code doesn't work is because it's looking for the whole string to replace (e.g. all three bad characters in order) rather than any one of them.

To replace any of the three, you'd need something more like this:

```
line = line.Replace("ï", " ").Replace("¿", " ").Replace("½", " ");
```

But, depending on your requirements, you might be better off cleaning the string by looping through each character and just checking if it's ASCII or alphanumeric or whatever you need it to be and rebuilding the clean string character by character.

Comment: Is there a way to I can tell it to replace all extended ascii (126 - 255) character with ""

Comment: For that, you'd have to use the second example.  Loop through the chars in the string, cast them to ints, and then you can check if they're in a valid range.

Comment: @user3537446 .NET stores characters in UTF-16. Do you want all non-ASCII characters removed, or just those in the "extended ASCII" range (which I believe starts with 129)?

Comment: I only next HEX character A0 & E1 removed

Answer (score 0):

> *Is there a way to I can tell it to replace all extended ascii (126 - 255) character with ""*

One way to replace characters within a range of ascii valus is to treat the string as a `char[]`, select all the characters except the ones you don't want (those with an ascii value between 126 and 255), and then `Concat` the string together again:

```
line = string.Concat(line.Where(chr => chr < 126 || chr > 255));
```

Comment: Note that this replaces all characters not in ASCII (not just those in Extended ASCII - e.g., it'll remove UTF-16 surrogates, CJK characters, etc.) as well as ASCII characters 126 (~) and 127 (the DEL character).

Comment: @JoeSewell true, thank you; I added an end range to the condition. The OP can change the range if they like, but they specified this range in their comment.

Comment: There are just two characters that I'm trying to remove which are HEX A0 and E1.  I try using the following statement but the characters are not removed - line.Replace("\xA0", "").Replace("\xE1", "").Replace("~", "").Replace("\t", "")

Comment: The code in your comment works for me. Are you forgetting to capture the result by assigning it to `line`?  `line = line.Replace("\xA0", "").Replace("\xE1", "").Replace("~", "").Replace("\t", "");` (and my answer works with those characters also).

Comment: It is part of a function there my statement is return line.Replace("\xA0", "").Replace("\xE1", "").Replace("~", "").Replace("\t", "")

Comment: Yeah, that should work fine. Please post sample code (that we can copy/paste) that reproduces the issue, since it's probably somewhere else.

Comment: Here a link of a text file that contains three sample records.  Record 1, column 508 & 528 has A0 character that I'm trying to remove, Record 2 & 4, Columns 320,321,323 has the character E1 that I'm trying to remove https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kljjoxqfhnwmm55/AAAJBoxExJFcdv5DZY5s8Ls9a?dl=0

Comment: I believe that the issue is with the File.ReadLines(srcFile) statement.  When reading the line that contains the extended ascii characters the values are changed.

Comment: The issue was with the ReadLine statement I needed to add the encoding type.

var lines = File.ReadLines(srcFile, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));